# Развитие грамматики

Tags: морфология

Здравствуйте! Несколько вопросов лингвистам и филологам: 1 - Почему современная грамматика русского языка такая бедная по сравнению с грамматикой чешского языка (да и других славянских)? 
Почему из русского языка так рано исчезли такие грамматические категории, как "Двойственное число", " Звательный падеж", развалилась старая система глагольных времён, исчезли краткие формы личных местоимений, исчез "Дательный Самостоятельный", количество типов склонения существительных сократилось с шести до трёх, а во множественном числе существительные вообще почти перестали различаться по родам и типам склонения; перестали склоняться краткие формы прилагательных и причастий; частица " бы" перестала изменяться, а ведь раньше изменялась, и ещё много чего исчезло, не буду всё перечислять.
С чем это связано? Почему морфология русского языка так сильно обеднела и упростилась по сравнению с другими славянскими языками? Ведь в других славянских всё это сохранилось и по сей день, но только не в русском. Или русский язык неславянский? Складывается такое впечатление, что большинство из перечисленных грамматических форм были просто напросто чужды древнерусским диалектам и присутствовали в них лишь временно. Или же это всё-таки следствие развития и эволюции языка? Чем больше людей на нём говорит, тем проще он становится? Но ведь древнерусский язык (условное название для всех древних восточнославянских диалектов и говоров) начал упрощаться задолго до того, как он получил такое широкое распространение. Откуда вообще в древнерусских диалектах эти вышеперечисленные грамматические формы? Влияние старославянского языка или наследство праславянского языка? Почему русский язык упростился, а другие славянские - едва ли! Например, в болгарском до сих пор используется очень развитая система глагольных времён, в словенском есть супин и двойственное число, в польском есть древние юсы, в чешском вообще много чего сохранилось. Конечно другие славянские тоже со временем немного упростились, но всё же, там это не так заметно, как в русском. Даже у ближайших родственников русского языка - украинского и белорусского - сохранилось больше архаизмов, чем в самом русском.

И второй вопрос: можно ли считать чешский язык самым сложным из всех славянских? Например, по сравнению с русским, чешский язык довольно сложный, у него очень богатые морфологическая, фонетическая и синтаксическая системы. Для сравнения: в чешском 14 типов склонения существительных, каждый из которых не похож на другой,в русском же их всего 3, при чем мягкий и твёрдый тип склонения довольно похожи.

Заранее благодарен за Ваши ответы!

Answer (score 1):

В таком виде это "неформат", здесь нет специалистов по иностранным языкам. Да и на вопрос объективно нельзя дать однозначного ответа.

Если же очень кратко, то разговоры о сравнительной простоте того или иного языка "вообще" - досужие сплетни. Нет той объективной линейки, которой можно эту простоту мерить. В каждом есть простые вещи, есть сложные. 
По сравнению с исходным общеславянским каждый из современных можно считать упрощением, просто это упрощение шло в разных направлениях. Чешский - не исключение.

И еще, постарайтесь задать вопросы по одному на тему. Или идите на другой ресурс, где любят дискуссии.

Comment: На каком сайте можно обратиться с этим вопросом?

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, сложность грамматической системы языка - **это  показатель его богатства или, напротив, недостаток?**

Мне кажется, что развитость и богатство определяются **другими критериями**, и **язык в своем развитии ищет более простые и изящные формы, которые могут выразить все необходимые оттенки значений**. Сложность и неуклюжесть любой формы - это не богатство, такая форма требует доработки мастера.

"Конечно другие славянские тоже со временем немного упростились", и это тоже показатель, так как  исчезновение одних форм  компенсируется развитием других возможностей. Наверное, богатство языка, его способность  к совершенствованию будет определяться силой духа русского народа, который пока не могут сломить даже самые трудные времена.

**Высказывания русских писателей о родном языке**

(1) Наш русский язык, более всех новых, может быть, **способен приблизиться к языкам классическим по своему богатству, силе,свободе расположения, обилию форм** (Н.А. Добролюбов - литературный критик, публицист).

(2)Что русский язык — **один из богатейших языков в мире**, в этом нет никакого сомнения (В.Г. Белинский - литературный критик, публицист).

(3) Главный характер нашего языка состоит в **чрезвычайной легкости, с которой все выражается на нем** — отвлеченные мысли, внутренние лирические чувствования, "жизни мышья беготня", крик негодования, искрящаяся шалость и потрясающая страсть (А.И. Герцен - писатель, публицист, философ, революционер).

(4) Русский язык открывается до конца **в своих поистине волшебных свойствах и богатстве лишь тому, кто кровно любит и знает "до косточки" свой народ** 
и чувствует сокровенную прелесть нашей земли (К. Г. Паустовский – писатель).

Comment: А вы на какой вопрос отвечали-то? Или вам уже все равно?

Comment: На вопрос "Почему русская грамматика такая бедная". Я  считаю, что чем больше падежей, тем грамматика сложнее, но не богаче, здесь другие критерии. А примеры говорят о том, что наши писатели восхищались богатством русского языка. Особенно мне нравится высказывание Герцена, который говорит о ЛЕГКОСТИ, С КОТОРОЙ НА РУССКОМ ЯЗЫКЕ МОЖНО ВЫРАЗИТЬ ВСЁ. Это и есть главное достоинство грамматики, а вовсе не ее сложность. Наша грамматика не бедная, она более простая, более развитая и более совершенная.